# Orbeon: Client Side JavaScript API - can't find element

Tags: orbeon

I have a trivial `xxf:script` on my form:

```
<xxf:script ev:event="DOMActivate">
 var msg = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("ctl-input");
  window.alert("Input: " + msg);
</xxf:script>
```

It should lookup `ctl-input` in the following model:

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<form>
    <section-3>
        <ctl-input/>
        <ctl-show/>
    </section-3>
</form>
</xf:instance>
```

but when it is run, it exits with the following error:

```
   Uncaught Cannot find control id ctl-input_.extend._findControl 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:138_.extend.getValue 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:138xf_861cb11f4997109affb7913426a4f463e1ad2cb0 
    @ new:104Server.callUserScript 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:132AjaxServer.handleResponseDom 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:133AjaxServer.handleResponseAjax 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:133YAHOO.util.Connect.handleTransactionResponse 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:56(anonymous function) 
    @ orbeon-e5b0ff6755fd59a52104ecab42b16b473214055e.js:56
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue()` takes the id of the control. If you created the form in Form Builder, the id is made of the name you gave, with the `-control` suffix. So you'll most likely want to call:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("ctl-input-control")
```

Comment: didn't solve my issue, posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741178)

Comment: Got it, I'll look into that separate question.