# Orbeon JavaScript API - Access to control value from within fr:section?

Tags: orbeon

There seems to be a problem related to `xf:triggers` embedded in a `fr:section`, see the following two sample forms.

Any known workarounds for this?

#### trigger not embedded in fr:section - works fine

```
<xh:html xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0" xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Test Form</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <form>
                    <message-section>
                        <message>my message</message>
                    </message-section>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:readonly="true">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>test-app</application-name>
                    <form-name>client-js-sample</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Test Form</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <singleton>false</singleton>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                <xf:output id="message" ref="message-section/message"/>
                <xf:trigger>
                    <xf:label>Show</xf:label>
                    <xxf:script ev:event="DOMActivate" type="javascript">
                        var message = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("message");
                        window.alert("message:" + message);
                    </xxf:script>
                </xf:trigger>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

#### trigger embedded in fr:section - doesn't work

As soon as `xf:trigger` is embedded in an `fr:section`, the Orbeon JavaScript API doesn't find the control `message` anymore. Here's the same rudimentary form, except for an additional `fr:section`.

```
<xh:html xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0" xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Test Form</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <form>
                    <message-section>
                        <message>my message</message>
                    </message-section>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:readonly="true">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>test-app</application-name>
                    <form-name>client-js-sample</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Test Form</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <singleton>false</singleton>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                <fr:section>
                    <xf:label>Test Section</xf:label>
                    <xf:output id="message" ref="message-section/message"/>
                    <xf:trigger>
                        <xf:label>Show</xf:label>
                        <xxf:script ev:event="DOMActivate" type="javascript">
                       var message = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("message");
                        window.alert("message:" + message);
                    </xxf:script>
                    </xf:trigger>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the section is an XBL control, and when your control is inside an XBL control, in the generated HTML, the id of the container is added as a prefix to the id of your control. So you can use:

```
var messageControl = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "message"]')[0];
alert(ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(messageControl));
```

For more on this, see the section of the documentation on [how to use `getValue()` and `setValue()` on forms created with Form Builder](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html#for-forms-created-in-form-builder).

Comment: Thanks! Also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms-doc/pull/9)  for a minor fix in the [new doc section](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html#for-forms-created-in-form-builder)

Comment: Yes, I missed `-control`, thank you for the correction. And your PR has been merged.